# Interest Rate Options - OTC vs Exchange, vol difference

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, trading, interest-rate-swap

I understand that Exchange Traded Interest Options (USD Libor 3m or Euribor 3m) trade with a lower volatility than the respective Cap or Floor for an equivalent structure.

Can anyone give any colour as to the specific reasons for this? Liquidity / One-Way demand in OTC?  And are there any research / papers on this area. Thanks for help.

Comment: In my experience, anything OTC always trades with a higher bid-offer than the exchange-traded equivalent. My guess is that on an exchange, all the quotes get aggregated and it's just more competitive, with multiple market-makers transparently competing against each other. In an OTC market, you ask multiple market-makers for a quote (usually via Bloomberg chat) and they all submit their quotes, without seeing each others quotes. So it's less competitive, you can't continuously improve your quotes and try to move ahead of other market-makers (cause you don't see their quotes).

Comment: What listed option is equivalent to a cap/floor on 3mL?

Comment: Additionally, OTC itself is more expensive, capitalwise.